# Proving that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{c^{-n}}{n!}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{c^{-n}}{n!}$ is convergent.

I invoked the limit comparison with the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{c^n}{n!}$ which is absolutely convergent (and hence convergent).

I got $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{c^{-n}}{n!}}{\frac{c^n}{n!}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!n!}$.

I am not sure where to go from here. Would it be correct to write that $\frac{1}{n!n!}\rightarrow0$ ($n\rightarrow\infty$), and hence by the limit comparison test the series is convergent? Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: That's not how comparison test works. If you knew that $\sum c^n/n!$ converges absolutely, then $\sum (c^{-1})^n/n!$ converges as well.

Comment: A factorial is a good sign that ratio test can be used . $ (n+1)!=n!(n+1) $

Comment: $$\frac{\frac{c^{-n}}{n!}}{\frac{c^n}{n!}}\ne\frac1{n!n!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Easier to notice that

$$ \sum \frac{ c^{-n} }{n!} = e^{1/c} $$

So as long as $c \neq 0$, we have convergence.

Comment: This is wrong. This series sums to $\exp(1/c)$, not $\exp(-1/c)$. (Note you would also need to shift the index, so the original series actually converges to $e^{1/c}-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ratio test:$$\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{\frac{c^{-n-1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{c^{-n}}{n!}}=\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac1{c\times(n+1)}=0<1.$$

Comment: Provided $c\ne0$.

Comment: If $c=0$, then the statement itself doesn't make sense.